# Where is the \ on Swiss Mac Layout (Home Folder Symbol)?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I just moved to Switzerland and on my new computer I am unable to find the \ symbol.

Does anyone know the shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

To find which key produces what character on any layout, you can use Apple's [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/14.0/mac/14.0).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Found it in an [old post](http://www.innoq.com/blog/st/2003/12/backslash_on_mac_os_x.html). It is mapped at <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd>, really weird.

Comment: Really weird is that mac doesn't have Alt. Using  Alt key on Windows keyboard doesn't change that.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Opt is Alt, depending on the keyboard used.